# Managing two config files (test and production) with git

Tags: php, git

As is usual for a PHP/MySQL project, I have a config file with database credentials. 
I test on my own local LAMP set up and do a git push to the live site.
The database name, user and password are different on the two.

What is the best practice for managing the two config.php files?

Could I make local edits to change from prod to test, but not commit that one file? That's assuming there are no other changes that need to be made to the file.

Or is there anything equiv to #ifdef in PHP? I know there's no preprocessor!

Comment: i guess there would be no preprocessor to the `PHP hypertext preprocessor` :) ... I handle this by having my configs split in local/stableDev/staging/prod specific directories, and on each specific implementation i symlink to the appropriate path in the git clone.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of that. I experimented with a "local" remote and it works for me.

Comment: environment variables is the most common solution I've seen to this problem. https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv is a popular package for sourcing an `.env` file

Comment: Looks very good. And the sensitive data (passwords) don't' have to be in the source. I'll fetch a copy and give it a try.